# Bad AccountQueryRs from QuickBooks Enterprise 2013

Tags: enterprise, quickbooks, qbxml

Using this QBXML request against QB Enterprise 2013 (by one of our users)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError">
    <AccountQueryRq>
      <ActiveStatus>All</ActiveStatus>
      <IncludeRetElement>ListID</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>EditSequence</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>Name</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>FullName</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>IsActive</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>Sublevel</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>AccountType</IncludeRetElement>
      <IncludeRetElement>AccountNumber</IncludeRetElement>
    </AccountQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I get a response in which the Fullname element for each Account only includes the Account Name, without the full Parent path (Fullname). Here's an example. Note that the Sublevel is 1, so there should be a parent reference in the Fullname element, but there is not:  it is the same as the Name element here.

```
...
      <AccountRet>
        <ListID>1260000-896890713</ListID>
        <EditSequence>1006542642</EditSequence>
        <Name>Contra Account</Name>
        <FullName>Contra Account</FullName>
        <IsActive>false</IsActive>
        <Sublevel>1</Sublevel>
        <AccountType>Bank</AccountType>
        <AccountNumber>3</AccountNumber>
      </AccountRet>
...
```

I would also note that the same thing has happened for that user, with a CustomDetailReportQueryRs ...where other QuickBooks editions return a Fullname it is only returning an account Name.

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...this situation is caused by the user having the following Preference turned on in QuickBooks:

Edit > Preferences > Accounting > Company Preferences > *Show lowest subaccount only*

The fix was to use the ParentRef data in each AccountRet to link it to it its parent Account data.

*Thanks to Karl Irvin for a heads-up which helped me solve this.*